# How to web-scraping with Python2.7 in Debian from a combined table?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, append

I want to web-scraping a table from a website.
My code is running correctly, I get the all 'td' informations in the table, but there is an extra information inside the 'tr', what I can't web-scraping.

The html source looks like this:

[image]

My code is here:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]

browser.get('https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ams/arrivals')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):
    temp_data = []   
    for data in record.find_all("td"):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('utf-8'))
    newlist = filter(None, temp_data)
    datatable.append(newlist)
```

How can I get this information: Tuesday, Nov 07 inside the 'tr', the 'data-date=' and add to my output?

Comment: If you follow the requests made by your browser when retrieving that page, you might see a call made to https://api.flightradar24.com/common/v1/airport.json?code=ams Parsing jsons is usually faster than scraping websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `record.attrs["data-date"]` to scrape value of `data-date` attribute as below:

```
for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):
    temp_data = [record.attrs["data-date"]]   
    for data in record.find_all("td"):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('utf-8'))
    newlist = filter(None, temp_data)
    datatable.append(newlist)
```

Comment: Hm... are you sure? I got output `[[u'Wednesday, Nov 08', '3:35 PM', ' KL1168', 'Helsinki (HEL)-', 'KLM -', 'B738 (PH-BCB) ', 'Landed 3:19 PM'], [u'Wednesday, Nov 08', '3:35 PM', ' KL1702', 'Madrid (MAD)-', 'KLM (SkyTeam Livery) -', 'B739 (PH-BXO) ', 'Landed 3:20 PM'] ...]`